# HTML line break in string

Tags: xml, xslt, line-breaks, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a Form on a Webpage, where the user has the possiblility to type a text in a textarea. After the form is submitted i want to generate a PDF.

Up to now the generation of the the PDF is working, but i have an issue with the line breaks from the textarea.

After submitting the form i have the following:

```
<Content>this is the first line<br><br>second line<br>third line<Content>
```

When i select the Content-element in the XSLT the content of the PDF looks

```
this is the first line<br><br>second line<br>third line
```

how can i get the line breaks to the PDF?

I already tried to replace the `<br>` with `&#xA;` and add the attribute `linefeed-treatment="preserve"`, but is not working.

The XML after the transformation looks like:

```
...
<fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
this is the first line&#xA;&#xA;second line&#xA;third line
</fo:block>
...
```

Comment: It should work.  I get the line-breaks when I try your example `fo:block` with AH Formatter, and the FOP compliance page (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html) says that it also supports `linefeed-treatment`.

Comment: I agree with Tony that it should work and your FO markup at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVg produces a PDF with line breaks. What I don't understand is why a form submission of a textarea would create `br` elements and not directly line breaks.

Comment: Did you try &#10; and is that the same result?

Comment: Also you state that the XML after "transformation" looks like the result you stated. In what way is it transformed? It certainly is not with pure XSLT because "br" is an open element with no end tag (in HTML). You must have code somewhere that does a custom transformation or you are changing <br> to <br/>